# Can't find error with importing css into html

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to all this but I've done it quite a few times now and should probably be able to find the error. But i can not figure out why the css document won't import to my html. I search around first and went to W3Schools.com to read how to use external documents however i can not find why it won't work. Sorry if the answer is painfully obvious but here is my code. Thanks in advance! 
(Using NotePad++ if that matters at all)

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="DeveloperLogMain.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="spreadsheet" href="DeveloperLogMain.css">
    </head>

    <body id='body'>
        <div id='head'>
            <h1 id='title'><b>Developing Log</b></h1>
        </div>

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div id='navbar'>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'><b>Home</b></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><b>HTML</b></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><b>CSS</b></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><b>JavaScript</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id='footcontainer'>

            <footer id='footer'><b>End Of Log</b></footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the css document is called "DeveloperLogMain.css".
cointaining

```
#head {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

#title {
    background-color: DarkRed;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-color: black;
}

#footcontainer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#navbar {
    float: left;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 90px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: DarkRed;
    text-align: center;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

#footer {
    background-color: DarkRed;
    text-align: center;
    height: 25px;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rel` should be equal to stylesheet not spreadsheet:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet " href="DeveloperLogMain.css">
```

Comment: i've changed it to stylesheet and still not importing for some reason.

Comment: its myPc>documents>code>css. Do i need to somehow implement the folders into the link? I usually have them in a desktop folder but i didnt this time.

Comment: If it is then the link should be: `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet " href="css/DeveloperLogMain.css">`

Comment: still have nothing. @chinloyal

Comment: What exactly is in DeveloperLogMain.css, can you add it to your answer? @JD

Comment: Also check your browser console to see if there was an error loading the file.

Comment: edited in the css file. also i am getting an error saying file not loaded in the browser console. @chinloyal

Comment: Okay so that still means your href is still incorrect. Can you list all the files and folders in your _code_ folder? @JD

Comment: it goes mypc>documents>coding>css / javascript/ html. And the only thing in the ccs folder is the file containing the css code "DeveloperLogMain.css" @chinloyal

Comment: Ok then if you have the html file in an html folder then you need this: `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet " href="../css/DeveloperLogMain.css">`

Comment: That got it. just real quick can you explain what the periods did before the css/developerlogmain.ccs? @chinloyal

Comment: @JD Since your html file is in a folder. The dots tell the html file to step out of it's directory then step into the css directory. If you don't want to be confused by the dots then you can just add a forward slash before css `/css/DeveloperLogMain.css` to tell the html file to start from the root directory then go to css folder.